# Stucking on creating connection in model - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, datamodel

I connect my sql database to Power BI. I got sth like 80.000 rows and I have two additional calculated columns that get previous vales. Here is a code   `Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "prev_action3", each try #"Added Custom" { [Index] -1 } [Action Type] otherwise null) "`  When I click close & apply I got stuck in "Creating connection in model" with over an hour now with nooutput. Without 2 columns close &apply cost like 1-2 minutes. I already tried this one https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/stucking-on-creating-connection-in-model/m-p/276796 , but it does not change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried the Solution above, still doeswn't work. Stuck at Creating Connection in Model.

This is happening after September2021 update of PowerBI Desktop.

I tried degrading to previous version od Power BI Desktop(August2021) Version. It is fixed now.

Comment: How to downgrade my version to August2021?Do I have to reinstall Power Bi?

Comment: yes. remove and then install new version

Comment: Nothing is wrong in the uploading, only in what it shows you, you can look at my answer on this thread

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it yet (I've got the same problem), but you can get older versions from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/desktop-latest-update-archive?tabs=powerbi-desktop

Woo!  Worked first time after installing August 2021.  Looks like something broken in Sept 2021

Comment: I downgraded my version to August but still stuck in Evaluating and creating connection model :/ . I hope they will soon fix this

Answer (score 2):

**This is a bug from PBi but nothing is wrong**

*If you already had this report going well before :*

Power BI decided (or not) to not show anymore the numbers of rows it is counting.

You feel like it's stuck and not working anymore --> do not worry, still going the same speed as before, it is just not telling you

Here are some links on the question :

[Power Bi community : creating connection](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/stucking-on-creating-connection-in-model/m-p/276796)

[Reddit : creating connection](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerBI/comments/qbkp3f/stuck_creating_connection_in_the_model/)

Answer (score 1):

Same here, stuck on creating connection in model on MYSQL database after Sept2021 Update. Can't believe I have to downgrade it...

Edit: Got it to work downgrading to August version.

Answer (score 1):

Yep same here - I went from the August 2021 release to October 2021 and the problem occurs in this later version too. It just gets stuck on the "creating connection in model...". I saved the August 2021 installer so will be reverting.

After downgrading to the August release my problem was resolved. Issue is going to be fixed in the November 2021 release apparently. See the link below which includes links to get previous versions (on page 5).

[Stucking on creating connection in model - Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69371312/stucking-on-creating-connection-in-model-power-bi)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an optical glitch only. My models also don't perform a rowcount anymore when refreshing the data, however after a while the data does get refreshed, so the data is being loaded in the background.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and to downgrade the pbi version worked very well.

I found the previous versions in this following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/desktop-latest-update-archive?tabs=powerbi-desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally stumbled across a fix for my problem. My Power Query was a Web.contents() Get api request and it simply could not get past the Enable Load into model and I was getting the same in progress timer indefinitely.

It turns out, the API response was returning a nested json which is equivalent to table of tables and I think each table, however small, is loaded by a thread.

Fix for me was to navigate under home file menu Option & Settings -> Global Options and set the Maximum Number of Simultaneous Evaluations to more than 1 (which it was by default)

[See attached screenshot of Global Options menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWyXt.png)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, This issue has been for a long time. The one way to overcome is access the query in the advanced editor, copy and paste it as a new query and then load it would work fine. However, if you already have a working report you might have to redo the data model should there be one.